# BeautifulSoup multiple page error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python. I want to retrieve data but the script only records one page.

```
import json
import urllib2

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

for i in range(12000,12200):   
    page="https://www.qualibat.com/resultat-de-la-recherche/mcp-peinture-{}".format(i)
    html = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
print data
```

Comment: what is your question? and what is the error?

Comment: I recommend you read the following to improve your questions in SO: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The last two lines will only execute once. If you want to run those 200 times as well, just indent them four spaces into the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need to iterate the URL in a range and extract the information. All you miss is the print method is out of the for loop.

```
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

for i in range(12000,12002):   
    page="https://www.qualibat.com/resultat-de-la-recherche/mcp-peinture-{}".format(i)
    html = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
    print data
```

**Update:**
With an exception handler the code now looks like:

```
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

for i in range(12000,12002):
    page="https://www.qualibat.com/resultat-de-la-recherche/mcp-peinture-{}".format(i)
    try:
        html = requests.get(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
        data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
        print(data)
    except:
        print "Error in scrapping: "+page
```

Output:

```
{'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'HomeAndConstructionBusiness', 'name': 'ZANELLO ETS', 'email': 'contact@zanello.fr', 'telephone': '02 33 77 11 22', 'numberOfEmployees': '165', 'foundingDate': '01/01/1925', 'address': {'@type': 'PostalAddress', 'streetAddress': "RUE DE L'ANCIENNE GARE BP 26", 'addressLocality': 'TESSY SUR VIRE', 'postalCode': '50420', 'addressCountry': 'FR'}}
{'@context': 'http://schema.org', '@type': 'HomeAndConstructionBusiness', 'name': 'ZENONE G. CONSTRUCTIONS', 'email': 'info@zenone.fr', 'telephone': '02 33 77 29 00', 'numberOfEmployees': '23', 'foundingDate': '14/01/1985', 'address': {'@type': 'PostalAddress', 'streetAddress': 'ZI DE LA CHEVALERIE BP 253', 'addressLocality': 'SAINT LO CEDEX', 'postalCode': '50003', 'addressCountry': 'FR'}}
```

N.B.: I have reduced the range from 12200 to 12002. Adjust it as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks but i would like a range bigger (12000-15000) but i have only one record in output

Comment: As you can see in the output, there are one record in each loop. So, we are getting two records for two iterations. So, what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Thanks but it stop scraping when theres no data (attribute error )how to continue with other pages

Comment: Use an exception handler [showed in here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) inside the loop. Updated my code.